Import a design from Figma to Android Studio
I'm trying to use Relay to pass my Figma design to Android Studio.
When I copy my Figma link I have this error "https://www.figma.com/design/dZtxaZ77cboSxhS2DyLwSV/APP?node-id=0%3A1&t=9zQOHJXE13qahQso-1 is not a valid URL. Valid Figma design URLs must start with: "https://www.figma.com/file...". I've been searching and I cannot find any pages in my Figma workspace that strart like that, my links are like https://www.figma.com/desing... Any suggestions or alternatives?

any solution found

I think that it is bug of figma.
My solution works
Just do what is said in this error - replace /design/ with
/file/ in URL that is:
https://www.figma.com/design/dZtxaZ77cboSxhS2DyLwSV/APP?node-id=0%3A1&t=9zQOHJXE13qahQso-1
to
https://www.figma.com/file/dZtxaZ77cboSxhS2DyLwSV/APP?node-id=0%3A1&t=9zQOHJXE13qahQso-1
Then insert this URL into "Figma Source URL" field in Android
Studio
File -> New -> Import UI Packages...

This didn't work for me :( Has this changed?
